# Cannot install Ubuntu server on Gigabyte mini PC

Tags: server, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu server on a used Gigabyte brand mini PC but I keep having issues. I got all the way to the end of the install, and then I get the `Sorry, there was a problem completing the installation` message. I got this when trying to install both Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04.

I checked the USB stick I was using to install Ubuntu 20.04 and found a partition called `writable` with what look like error logs in it, however I don't know where to begin looking through them.

Log dump:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N-hh7iObud3yirxrXgLAj5QDfXEdqSuF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Where to begin?  With a text editor!  Without seeing your logs, it is impossible to tell you the actual cause.  A common cause is having chosen an incorrect mirror.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas If it's relevant, I have no internet access for this device (I don't have an ethernet cable, I have a USB wifi dongle but it doesn't seem to see it during the installation. There are a lot of log files. Should I just upload them all as an archive?

Comment: Yes, uploading the bunch is probably a good place to start.